# SwiftUI - How to update/redraw an image

Tags: swiftui

New to swiftUI here and looking for a simple way to redraw an image when a button is click. In the project, black square-shaped image is the default, orange, and then gray. So depending on what is typed in the TextField, that color should get redrawn.  I'm using Observable Object and some binding to try accomplish this but somehow the image never gets redrawn, what am I missing?

```
import SwiftUI


class CloudImage: ObservableObject {
    @Published var url = "black"
    
    func changeUrl(name: String){
        self.url = name
        print(self.url)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var image = CloudImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Change Image Test")
            .padding()
        
        ImageContainer(image_name: image.url)
            
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Image", text: $image.url)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
    
            Button("Update"){
                image.changeUrl(name: image.url)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


//ImageContainer

struct ImageContainer: View {
    
    var image_name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(image_name)
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Change State to StateObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach, using a `StateObject` and passing a new url name when calling `changeUrl(...)`.
Works for me:

```
class CloudImage: ObservableObject {
    @Published var url = "globe"
    
    func changeUrl(name: String){
        url = name
        print("----> url: \(url)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var image = CloudImage() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Change Image Test")
            .padding()
        
        ImageContainer(image_name: image.url) 

        VStack {
            TextField("Image", text: $image.url)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
            Button("Update"){
                image.changeUrl(name: "house")  // <-- here
                // image.url = "house"  // alternative
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
    
}

struct ImageContainer: View {
    var image_name: String   // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: image_name)
    }
}
```